# How to play video in custom grid just like Instagram

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

[image: Instagram snapshot]

I have a search field similar to Instagram, I achieved it using flutter_staggered_grid_view and able to shows videos in the big boxes, but how can I play them when the user scroll. I am trying to use inview_notifier_list, but unable to succeed. I want to play the video only when the user scrolls down. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

I achieved this using VisibilityDetector. If 80% of the video is visible then play otherwise pause.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final deviceRatio = size.width / size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: controller.value != null && controller.value.initialized
              ? VisibilityDetector(
                  key: ObjectKey(controller),
                  onVisibilityChanged: (visibility) {
                    if (visibility.visibleFraction > 0.8) {
                      controller.play();
                    } else {
                      controller.pause();
                    }
                  },
                  child: CachedVideoPlayer(controller)
                )
              : Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Positioned.fill(
                    child: Container(
                      child: Image.network(
                        widget.image,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]